# Switching database connections in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I made a web application using PHP MySQL. Post development, I am required to add in the functionality of allowing archiving of yearly data, which translates to an adhoc solution where I copy the entire database.

The problem is, I have a standard 'connections.php' file which is included in all my php files for the system, that stores the database server authentication details, and name. The code is like this below :

```
$hostname_db_ntu = "localhost";
$database_db_ntu = "ntu";
$username_db_ntu = "root";
$password_db_ntu = "";
$db_ntu = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_ntu, $username_db_ntu, $password_db_ntu) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

So, how do I get my system to switch databases on the fly? I need to change the '$database_db_ntu' variable value basically. Is editing the php file using another php my only option?

(I am aware mysql_* is depreciated, and I have countered it as far as possible.)

EDIT : To clarify :

The whole system uses a database with multiple tables, and all the pages connect with that database using this include file whose code is above.

I need a solution, where I can in someway modify this 
included file to reflect the chosen database, and accordingly create the connection.

Comment: Change `mysql_*` to eg, `PDO`. And don't edit that file. It doesn't make any sense. Just create new connection when you need to connect to another database.

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated use `mysqli` and try to create a function to connect to database and pass host name, password, dbName, etc as parameters

Answer (score 2):

How about using an if.. else statement:

```
if ($dbcon1) {
$hostname_db_ntu = "localhost";
$database_db_ntu = "ntu";
$username_db_ntu = "root";
$password_db_ntu = "";
$db_ntu = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_ntu, $username_db_ntu, $password_db_ntu) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
} else {

//database connection2 here
}
```

You then need to pass a value for $dbcon1 to decide which connection to use.

Answer (score 1):

Make another database connection. That should work.

```
$db_ntu2 = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_ntu2, $username_db_ntu2, $password_db_ntu2) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: The tables in the two databases are exactly similar in structure and naming. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
      $hostname_db_ntu = "your host name";
       $database_db_ntu = "your database name";
       $username_db_ntu = "root or username you have set";
      $password_db_ntu = "";
     $db_ntu = mysql_connect($hostname_db_ntu, $username_db_ntu, $password_db_ntu) or    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

   $db_connect = mysql_select_db(" $database_db_ntu" ,$db_ntu) or die("!db");
```

Comment: This might have just given me an idea. Let me try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I did. I set session variables based on which version of the database the user wanted to use. Then, I edited my global 'connections.php' script as follows :

```
session_start();
$hostname_db_ntu = "localhost";
if(isset($_SESSION['version']))
$database_db_ntu = $_SESSION['version'];
else
$database_db_ntu = "ntu";
$username_db_ntu = "root";
$password_db_ntu = "";
$db_ntu = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_ntu, $username_db_ntu, $password_db_ntu) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

The advantage to this method is, I can allow the user to switch databases, without having to go and edit each of my php files which use the database.